# Android root access

Tags: android, root

I have a Google Nexus 7, and I've been developing on it. Only recently, however, have I become unable to access the /data/ directory using the file browser in eclipse. The device was never rooted, but now since I upgraded it, I believe that I have lost access to this. Is there any way to get eclipse to use the "run-as" command to access my app's data directory? How come I have suddenly lost access to this?

Is the only option left to root the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get eclipse to use the "run-as" command to access my app's data directory?

There is nothing for you to run "as" that would help here, AFAIK.

> How come I have suddenly lost access to this?

You should not have had access to it in the first place. If you did, that was a security flaw in the device, perhaps fixed by a firmware upgrade.

> Is the only option left to root the device?

You could not browse the `/data/` directory on production hardware. For example, you can browse `/data/` on the emulator.

Comment: Right. Perhaps I was thinking of the emulator instead.
Although, can I push files to the device using "run-as". In the shell, I can type `run-as packagename command` and then list the files in my `android:debuggable=true` app's data directory. Is it possible to use this to push files somehow?

Comment: @AStupidNoob: Not directly, AFAIK. But, you could use `run-as` in the shell to transfer files to/from external storage, then use DDMS, `adb push`/`adb pull`, or an MTP client to interact with external storage.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to given root permission by installing apk.
http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/features/how-to-root-nokia-x-and-get-access-to-google-play-store-and-google-now-508391